# Prevent arcanist from commiting to remote

Tags: git, phabricator, arcanist

This may be just a confusion of mine.

When I submit an phabricator revision, I see that (in some cases) arcanist commits my revision message to the remote repo?

Why is this happening?
Can i prevent this?

I don't want to merge and push unnecessary changes to the code base.

Comment: Does this seem to happen when you run the `arc land` command?

Comment: No, on arc diff, this is not about the autoclose commit

Comment: I have never heard of that before, sorry I can't be much help here.

Answer (score 1):

`arc diff` itself won't push any commit.
All that happens is that it creates a diff (`git diff`) and send those changes to Differential. This is not like a branch, your git repository is untouched.
From this diff a revision is created which will be used for this pre-push code review.

The message associated with this revision will be asked by default and will default to your commit message.

The remote repository is only changed if:

- You `git push` yourself
- If you use `arc land`

Arc land will do (by default) the following steps:

- Squash your changes (reduce to 1 commit)
- Checkout/update master
- Merge the branch into it
- Push to origin/master
- Delete the branch

Most of the `arc land` behavior can be tweaked, for example you can use `arc land --merge` to prevent squashing your commits and merge them as-is.